# After changing my voxel size from .03m to 1m, my mesh sculpture disappeared and I don't knowhow to get it back. How do I fix this?

Tags: sculpting

I am relatively new to blender so I'm hoping this will be an easy fix... I was sculpting a samurai mask with my Voxel size at .03m but then I changed it to 1 m and my mesh dissapeared. I tried changing it back but it is not re-appearing again. I've tried like hell to find an answer on how to fix this, but to no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try uploading some screenshots of the problem in question, it will improve your question.